# How can a database be connected to a blockchain 'record'?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

If I have state stored in a contract for say dbkeys, and I want to use the keys to access some data stored in a normal off-chain database, is there an expert means of doing that?

I think we could simply access the dbkeys via a getter method which sends back the data as return to the calling method in the contract instance. But my question is really can we link at an architectural level the dbkey stored in state in a contract on the blockchain with the actual dbkey as used in an off-chain database?